# Datatables.net dynamic columns

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

We are currently using [datatables](http://datatables.net) with MVC 4, which is working well for static columns

What we are currently struggling with is to find a nice way to dynamically create the datatables table.

For example, we have a model which contains a list of columns:-

```
public class SampleModel    {
    public test1 {get;set;}
    public test2 {get;set;}
    public List<TableColumn>AditionalColumns { get ; set;}
}


public class TableColumn
{
    public TableColumn() { }

    public TableColumn(string ColumnHeader, string ColumnValue, int ColumnWidth)
    {
        this.ColumnHeader = ColumnHeader;
        this.ColumnValue = ColumnValue;
        this.ColumnWidth = ColumnWidth;
    }

    public string ColumnHeader { get; set; }
    public string ColumnValue { get; set; }
    public int ColumnWidth { get; set; }  
}
```

We can convert the data into the appropiate format (json) required by Datatables, however, cannot find away to dynamically build and create the columns on the fly.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you rendering your entire table out to the client or are you wanting to dynamically add/remove columns with ajax calls?

Comment: hi, ive look at your answer below, and unfortunatly, it still doesnt quite answer my question. The number of columns that we have is x, ie. we dont know how many columns there are, we are trying to build the table dynamically, not show or hide certain columns. hope this makes sense

Comment: Sorry, I've added an update. Not sure if it will help though. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending all the data back as json in one go, you can use the `fnShowHide` function to dynamically hide/display the columns.

```
 fnShowHide(0);
```

As an example I would dynamically build up filtering buttons as follows:

```
$('#aTable').find('th').each(function( index ) {             
        var filterButton = $('<button/>',
    {
        text: $(this).text(),       
        click: function () {  fnShowHide(index); }
    });

    $('#AddRemoveColumnPlaceHolder').append(filterButton);
});
```

This takes returns the header rows which are returned from your view, loops each creating a button and mapping the `fnShowHide` with the index.

Here is a complete working example in jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hutchonoid/5xsvN/7/

For the info on the show hide functionality see here for more info:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/show_hide.html

**Update**

Sorry I misunderstood the question, I thought you wanted to dynamically add columns (i.e. hide/display) on a rendered table.

If I were you I would do it like this.

Render the table out as normal using razor or with jQuery.
Add your columns to the table using jquery i.e.

```
// dynamically add the column
$("#aTable th:last").parent().append('<th>Col 3</th>')
```

Then call the `.dataTable()` last.

The only reason I say this is because from my past experience I find it much easier to manipulate the dom structure using standard javascript/jQuery.

Sorry if this doesn't answer your question fully.

Comment: Unfortunatly the columns could be completly different, it all depends what columns have been added to columns list. We need to capture the column header also for display

Answer (score 0):

Simon, based on your comment to the above I'm guessing you're looking for something like this:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      @foreach(TableColumn tc in Model) {
        <th>@tc.ColumnHeader</th>
      }
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Then initialize your datatables like normal using your favorite Controller/Action Method to serve your json.